# How to persist changes made by the NavigationToolbar on a periodically updated graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 GUI application. This application shows a graph (with my default `xlim` and `ylim`) that gets updated every second, a real-time graph basically. This functionality I have, but I want to add a `NavigationToolbar` so one can zoom in/out the graph.

I added the toolbar to my layout and it gets displayed. So far so good. Now I zoom in, the graph gets zoomed in, but once the graph gets periodically updated the `xlim` and `ylim` are defaulted again and the zoom is gone. What properties I need to call from the toolbar so I can save them and pass them to my `_update_canvas` function? I looked at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/axes_api.html, and noticed the function `get_ylim`. So i tried as followed:

`self._dynamic_ax.set_ylim(self._dynamic_ax.get_ylim())` and `self._dynamic_ax.set_ylim(self._dynamic_ax2.get_ylim())`

As well as:
`self._dynamic_ax.set_navigate(True)`

However these didn't work. How can I persist the settings set by `NavigationToolbar`? Not only the zoom but also the pan.

A minimal runnable code sample:

```
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


buffer_size = 120
t = [t for t in range(buffer_size)]
bitthrough = [t for t in range(buffer_size)]
errors = bitthrough[::-1]


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PCANbus sniffer")
        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 400))
        self.show()


class MyTableWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab_graph = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_info = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_graph, "PCANbus occupation")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_info, "PCANbus information")

        self.tab_graph.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.dynamic_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(6, 4)))
        self.tab_graph.layout.addWidget(self.dynamic_canvas)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.dynamic_canvas, self)
        self.tab_graph.layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)

        self._dynamic_ax = self.dynamic_canvas.figure.subplots()
        self._dynamic_ax.set_xlabel("time (s)")
        self._dynamic_ax.set_xlim(-5, 125)
        self._dynamic_ax.set_ylabel("Throughput (%)", color="black")
        self._dynamic_ax.set_ylim(-5, 120)
        self._dynamic_ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="black")
        # self._dynamic_ax.set_navigate(True)

        self._dynamic_ax2 = self._dynamic_ax.twinx()
        self._dynamic_ax2.set_ylabel("Errors (%)", color="blue")
        self._dynamic_ax2.set_ylim(-4, 100)
        self._dynamic_ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="blue")
        #self._dynamic_ax2.set_navigate(True)

        self.tab_graph.setLayout(self.tab_graph.layout)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._update_canvas)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def _update_canvas(self):

        self._dynamic_ax.clear()
        self._dynamic_ax.plot(t, bitthrough, color="black")
        self._dynamic_ax.set_xlabel("time (s)")
        self._dynamic_ax.set_ylabel("Throughput (%)", color="black")
        self._dynamic_ax.set_ylim(-5, 120) #self._dynamic_ax.get_ylim())
        self._dynamic_ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="black")

        self._dynamic_ax2.clear()
        self._dynamic_ax2.plot(t, errors, color="blue")
        self._dynamic_ax2.set_ylabel("Errors", color="blue")
        self._dynamic_ax2.set_ylim(-4, 100) #self._dynamic_ax2.get_ylim())
        self._dynamic_ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="blue")

        self._dynamic_ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = App()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

My real `_update_canvas` function:

```
    def _update_canvas(self):

        wh_green = [a <= b for a, b in zip(bitthrough, llvl)]
        wh_orange = [a > b and a <= c
                     for a, b, c in zip(bitthrough, llvl, lvl)]
        wh_red = [a > b for a, b, in zip(bitthrough, lvl)]

        # self._dynamic_ax.clear()
        # self._dynamic_ax2.clear()

        self._dynamic_ax.fill_between(
            t, 0, bitthrough, where=wh_red, color="red", interpolate=True
        )
        self._dynamic_ax.fill_between(
            t, 0, bitthrough, where=wh_orange, color="orange", interpolate=True
        )
        self._dynamic_ax.fill_between(
            t, 0, bitthrough, where=wh_green, color="green", interpolate=True
        )
        # self._dynamic_ax.plot(t, bitthrough, color="black")
        # self._dynamic_ax.set_xlabel("time (s)")
        # self._dynamic_ax.set_ylabel("Throughput (%)", color="black")
        # #self._dynamic_ax.set_ylim(self._dynamic_ax.get_ylim())
        # self._dynamic_ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="black")

        # self._dynamic_ax2.plot(t, errors, color="blue")
        # self._dynamic_ax2.set_ylabel("Errors", color="blue")
        # #self._dynamic_ax2.set_ylim(self._dynamic_ax2.get_ylim())
        # self._dynamic_ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="blue")

        self._plot1.set_ydata(bitthrough)
        self._plot2.set_ydata(errors)

        # logging.debug("redrawing graph!!")
        self._dynamic_ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
```

The solution of @DizietAsahi doesn't work while using `fill_between`. The area gets overwritten and not cleared. So they are displayed on top of eachother.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to not clear the figure at each update. Instead, store a reference to the Line2D artists created by `plot()` and update the {x|y}data (using `set_data()` or `set_ydata()`) in your update function.

```
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


buffer_size = 120
t = np.linspace(0, 100, buffer_size)
bitthrough = 120*np.random.random(size=(buffer_size,))
errors = bitthrough[::-1]


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PCANbus sniffer")
        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(640, 400))
        self.show()


class MyTableWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab_graph = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_info = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_graph, "PCANbus occupation")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_info, "PCANbus information")

        self.tab_graph.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.dynamic_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(6, 4)))
        self.tab_graph.layout.addWidget(self.dynamic_canvas)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.dynamic_canvas, self)
        self.tab_graph.layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)

        self._dynamic_ax = self.dynamic_canvas.figure.subplots()
        self._dynamic_ax.set_xlabel("time (s)")
        self._dynamic_ax.set_xlim(-5, 125)
        self._dynamic_ax.set_ylabel("Throughput (%)", color="black")
        self._dynamic_ax.set_ylim(-5, 120)
        self._dynamic_ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="black")
        # self._dynamic_ax.set_navigate(True)

        self._dynamic_ax2 = self._dynamic_ax.twinx()
        self._dynamic_ax2.set_ylabel("Errors (%)", color="blue")
        self._dynamic_ax2.set_ylim(-4, 100)
        self._dynamic_ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="blue")
        #self._dynamic_ax2.set_navigate(True)


        ##
        ## Create plots here (initially empty)
        ##
        self._plot1, = self._dynamic_ax.plot(t, np.empty(shape=(buffer_size,)), color="black")
        self._plot2, = self._dynamic_ax2.plot(t, np.empty(shape=(buffer_size,)), color="blue")
        self._fill1 = self._dynamic_ax.fill_between(t, 0, bitthrough, color="orange")

        self.tab_graph.setLayout(self.tab_graph.layout)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._update_canvas)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def _update_canvas(self):
        bitthrough = 120*np.random.random(size=(buffer_size, ))
        errors = bitthrough[::-1]

        ##
        ## update the content of the plots here, without clearing the figure
        ##
        self._plot1.set_ydata(bitthrough)
        self._plot2.set_ydata(errors)
        self._fill1.remove()
        self._fill1 = self._dynamic_ax.fill_between(t, 0, bitthrough, color="orange")

        self._dynamic_ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = App()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

**EDIT**
I've added some code for handling `fill_between()`.
`fill_between()` returns a `PolyCollection` which is a pain to update, so the best option there is to remove the `PolyCollection` and re-create it at each update (but not clear the whole figure).

Comment: Thanks! Really like this solution, elegant and simple. This wasn't my real `update` function. I added the one I have now with the old code in comments to my OP. Really thought the `fill_between` wouldn't work. Turns out it's intertwined by magic

Comment: Ok, so I guess I didn't test enough. This doens't work while using `fill_between`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've added more code for dealing with `fill_between()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This works perfectly. Added `_fill_red` and `_fill_green` myself.